# How to choose values from one column having another column and do that per user in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 3 columns: Id, Type and sum. I need to choose the Type based on max value of sum column and to do that per user. For example, if there are 3 types per user 1, like: bank, shop and other and the biggest sum is corresponding for bank, then in my result column for user 1 it should be 'bank' everywhere. In the example below for user 2 the result is 'shop'. Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) for values of `Type` by maximal `sum` per `ID`:

```
df['result'] = df.set_index('Type').groupby('ID')['sum'].transform('idxmax').to_numpy()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This code helped me a lot many times. Don't know why my first 'thank you' comment was deleted. I have another question here - is that possible to get the second max value from the same data? Thanks.

Comment: @AnnaBalanyk - Is possible convert dataframe to text, for possible copy data?

Comment: No, it's not. I solved that problem in other way, by making a copy of dataset where I deleted the values that I got as max, so then I took the next max values. But maybe there is an easiest way when I don't write so much code. 
Is there also another way of using transform function to do another tricky thing? I need to get the first product - it should me minimal year and max case. For example, if there are 2 products in 2010, it should return kasko, because the case is higher.https://imgur.com/CUv6yjU